# VirtualBox Win7 64 bit showing "Windowtitle" in tasklist as "N/A" via command line

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox

When searching for all processes running in my 32 bit PC in command line using the command: `tasklist /V`, my running VBox returns Windowtitle `test [Running] - Sun xVM VirtualBox`, but when doing the same search on my 64 bit PC, it returns N/A for Windowtitle.

Are there any settings I can change on my 64 bit PC to view the Windowtitle? I need the Windowtitle as I am doing a search command in a batch file like this:

```
FOR /f %%a in ('tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq test*"') do (
    set line=%%a
)
if "%line%" == "VirtualBox.exe" (
    GOTO loop2
)
```

Please help!